# Background-image: url() and clip in HTML/CSS- Parallax scrolling effect for clipped image

Tags: html, css, image, parallax, clip

I have the URL link to an image that I am supposed to use in creating an HTML/CSS webpage. I am to clip the image from left, right and bottom i.e crop the image from all these directions using clip property in CSS. Now, I'm should try to make it a background image to achieve parallax effect while scrolling.

How do I use the clip property and background-image:url() attribute together to achieve parallax effect on the clipped image?

NOTE: jquery and javascript are not to be used.

Comment: Provide code or working example

Comment: background-repeat: repeat-x; and background-position + animation.

Comment: you can use `background-position:fixed`

Comment: background-postion : fixed requires use of background-image, which in turn can only use a URL link as input further denying clipping properties on the image.

Comment: Well then use `position:fixed` (and `z-index`) on an `img` element, to place it in the background behind all other content, or something like that ... Your problem/requirement description is rather unspecific as of now, as to what exact effect you are looking for.

Comment: That does work. But that seems to create another problem, I am to use one image to achieve parallax at the beginning of the web page and another to use at the end of the web page. So postion: fixed is only helping achieve parallax for one image.